# MYSQL,NODEJS copy data to the same table than update the Cross reference table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I write a schedule programm  with a database, the classes can change from week to week, classes can be temporary or deleted or can be replaced

I have 3 tables

USERS (userID autoincrement,name,addres ...  )

CLASSES (classID autoincrement , week date, fix , deleted)

USERSANDCLASSES (classID,userID)

My problem is When a user try to see his next week, my programm try to copy the the relevant classes  from the past week and insert them into the same table with new ID , but it doesn't work on the Cross reference table.

```
"INSERT INTO classes (day,weekdate, fix, deleted) " +
        " SELECT day , '"+new_weekdate+"', fix, deleted " +
        " FROM classes WHERE weekdate='"+weekdate+"' AND fix='1' AND deleted='0'"
```

And after I try to do something like this

```
"INSERT INTO USERSANDCLASSES 
 VALUES  SELECT CLASSES.classID USERSANDCLASSES.userID FROM (CLASSES INNER JOIN
 USERSANDCLASSES ON CLASSES.classID= USERSANDCLASSES.UserID) WHERE 
 CLASSES.weekdate ='"+new_weekdate+"';
```

obviously it didn't work

How can I join the new classID-s with the user id-s. Is there any solution with sql?

Comment: It is always best to show the code you tried and its output.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: You have an extra `VALUES` in the second query. Also, you see to concatenate SQL with other data without escaping. This is probably prone to **SQL injection attacks**. Please use parameterised queries instead.